# I am not able to run python code open(arg) in Windows, recieving error

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, permissions, python

When trying to open file in Python, I receive this error.

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

I've checked execution policy, and also checked permission in Windows. I have the required permissions to read the file, and I tried setting the execution policy in Windows to unsigned a long with Bypass.

The only thing I haven't tried is logging into my Administrator account and storing python as the environment variable, and trying again, I want to avoid this if necessary as I do not want to Bypass my security policy. Even with me having the required permission in the account I am writing my script, I am not able to open the file using Python.

However, I am able to open files using Powershell.

I have full access to all the directories I am trying to access on both file permissions and directories. I am using Windows 10.

Comment: Are you trying to open read-only or read/write (or write-only)?   Are you testing the corresponding access in PowerShell?   What happens when you try to access the file from the Command Prompt or Windows Explorer (i.e., File Explorer)?   What do the file permissions look like (e.g., from file properties)?   And are you using Windows 7 or Windows 10 (or both)?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: I have tried open in read only and write as well. I tested in Powershell using "Invoke-item" I receive no error messages or permissions. However, when trying to open in python using open(filename) I receive permission error, I have python in the system32 environmental variable with Windows and also in the user profile I am using, I also checked permissions of the file and I am able to access.When trying to access from Command prompt I get the same error when running python as powershell. When accessing from Windows Explorer I am able to open the files just fine.

Comment: It appears my issue is resolved, I am not sure what the problem was but after waiting about an hour I am not able to make changes. Strange.